# Is it OK to say "for almost every natural number"?

Tags: measure-theory, terminology

Suppose you want to say that a predicate $P(x)$ holds for every sufficiently large natural number $n$.  I have seen several authors write "for almost every $n  \in \mathbb N$, $P(n)$" or "$P(n)$ a.e." to mean this.

I understand that the expression "almost every" almost always refers to a measure-theoretic notion.  However, since we're dealing with $\mathbb N$, a countable set, so the usual measure-theoretic interpretation doesn't work here.

My question is whether "$P(n)$ a.e." is a widely accepted expression even if it is about natural numbers.  If it is, I would like to use it because it's convenient and saves me a few keystrokes (penstrokes, chalkstrokes or whatever).

Comment: Why exactly doesn't the measure-theoretic notion work here?

Comment: @GitGud Exactly what measure can you put on $\Bbb N$ for which the measure zero sets are precisely the finite ones?

Comment: @GitGud: If $P(n)$ is true a.e for the counting measure, $P(n)$ never fails, right?

Comment: @Mike I don't know, but I don't see how it is relevant.

Comment: @Antoine No, take $P(n):\, n\text{ is even}$. The set of even integers has (counting) measure $+\infty$ because it isn't finite and obviously $\neg \exists m\in \mathbb N\forall n\ge m P(m)$.

Comment: @GitGud Sorry, I misunderstood you. (I thought you meant that 'all but finitely many' could be interpreted as almost every in a measure theoretic sense.)

Comment: @OP Yes, "almost every" is common notation in number theory for "all but finitely many".

Comment: @Mike To be honest I don't even know what I'm saying anymore. I asked a question to which I apparently knew the answer.

Comment: @Mike The examples I have seen are all about mathematical logic.  I'd be grateful if you could guide me to an example in number theory.

Comment: @Pteromys I can't give you a specific reference or anything but it's definitely common notation. "An integer in a number field is a unit in almost all of its localizations", "almost all primes are odd"... You see the notation regularly in number theory because so many statements are about countable sets (that have some exceptional set you want to discount - that happens to be finite)

Comment: I should say that it's a safe notation to use because in practice it will be obvious to the reader what is meant by it (all but finitely many or measure zero) when in context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not recommended. Better to say that "$P(n)$ except for finitely many $n$".

A related, more lax, notion is "$P(n)$ except on a set of natural density zero". Beware though that [natural density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density) is not a measure (for example, some subsets $A$ and $B$ of $\mathbb N$ can have a natural density while $A\cap B$ has not)

Comment: Though I also think "$P(n)$ except for finitely many $n$" works the best, I sometimes use "$P(n)$ for large values of $n$" or $P(n)$ as $n\to\infty$" if I think it will be clear.  Frankly, I wish we could all adopt the last one as the standard.